# Batch Export feature attribute to ASCII in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, ascii

I have around 160 feature classes that I need to convert into ascii files. Spatial statistics tool ---> Utilities ---> Export feature attribute to ascii only allows converting one file at a time. Is there any way to export all my features to ascii in one go? Any script written?

Comment: Please check following links                      1.http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/69825-Error-exporting-feature-attributes                                                  2.http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43502/batch-converting-ascii-into-feature-classes-using-shapefile-lists

Comment: Welcome to our site, ToNoY! Please take a minute to review our [faq], where you can learn about how to use comments and answers effectively.  In particular, as the owner of this question you have the ability to post *comments* beneath the question and any answers that are offered. Please don't use the answer box for that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I would try using the **[batch grid control](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000z000000)**.

Instead of double-clicking or using right-click to Open a tool, use right-click Batch.

If your 160 feature classes are all in the same workspace you should be able to multiple-select them in the Catalog window and drag them into the first column.

I tested it below and it seemed to run OK.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much PolyGeo, unfortunately, By default, it should take the 'output ascii name' as the 'input file name', but it doesn't.

Comment: To do the Output ASCII File names I entered "C:\temp\test.asc" and right-clicked to Fill the rest of the column with the same value.  I then manually entered a number to distinguish each.  The Default value is empty.