# Batch attribute table export

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, export, batch

How can I export multiple raster attribute tables at once, using the batch grid control tool mentioned here? 
[Batch Export feature attribute to ASCII in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46821/batch-export-feature-attribute-to-ascii/46840#46840)

I can't seem to find how to access the tool in ArcMap 10.0.

Comment: Hear is a helpful link, http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_batch_processing/00210000000w000000/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to right click on the tool that you want to use for batch. In your case, I think that the best tool is "[table to table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000027000000)".

Comment: thanks. just needed to find the right tool and the batch processing worked as usual.